# The error says "incompatible type when returning type of struct ..."

Tags: c

I am trying to compile the following code ,And I am getting an error on the
return line
The error says,
"incompatible type when returning type 'date..
Can someone please explain me the reason?

```
typedef struct Date Date;

struct Date{

int jour;
int mois;
int anner;

};

Date plus1(Date *p){


if((p->jour==30)&&(p->mois==12)){

    p->jour=1;
    p->mois=1;
    p->anner++;
 }
 else if(p->jour==30){

        p->jour=1;
        p->mois++;
  }
 else{

 p->jour++;
 }

  return p;

 }
```

Comment: You either want the function to be changed to `Date *plus(Date *p)` [I prefer this method--it is faster]. Or, keep your original definition and do `return *p;` You're mixing up a struct return with a struct pointer return.

Comment: Note that you don't need to return anything, since you are modifying the value pointed by `p` inside the function. Passing the pointer to the function is enough, unless your goal was to malloc a new instance within the function.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, a pointer is not the same type as the return type.

In your function signature, you specify

```
Date plus1(Date *p)
```

Which is fine, but note that p's type is not a date. P's type is a pointer to a date structure.

Your full function is

```
Date plus1(Date *p) {
... // Do stuff
return p;
}
```

The simple answer is that p is the address where the date is. The address is not the same as the struct, hence the types being incompatible. There's two good options going forwards: changing the return type or dereferencing p.

The first option would change the signature to

```
Date *plus1(Date*p)
```

Which is fine, but be aware that you'll get a pointer back. If you insist the type has to be a Date returned, the other option would be to change the return statement.

```
Date plus1(Date *p) {
... // Do stuff
return *p;
}
```

This would return the object itself.

However, this is speculation, but if you want to physically change p itself, you don't need to return the type, it'll be done by itself.

```
void plus1(Date *p)
```

Then when calling the function, you don't need to worry about the return. You can just call it and pass the address:

```
plus1(&foo);
```